# android custom icon class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am going to be creating a launcher app, and want to place icons dynamically on the screen.  I would like to have a custom icon class that i can pass a bitmap and tag to.  then place on the main activity..

I am unclear as to whether or not this is the way to set up that custom icon class and what it should extend instead of activity..
also not sure how to add it to the main activity view..

my custom icon class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GenIcon extends Activity{

    public GenIcon(Bitmap image, String imageTag){

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        imageView.setTag(imageTag);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

my main activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DragableIconActivity extends Activity {
    GenIcon icon;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        icon = new GenIcon(bitmap,"my icon");



    }
}
```